# How to reduce bootstrap navbar height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to reduce bootstrap navbar height ,What is the best solution to achieve this task , should i overwrite bootstrap css or any pure css solution ?

main.html

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default container-panel">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="z-index:10;">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <li>some other stuff</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.css

```
.navbar.container-panel {
  width:250px;
  margin-left: 760px;
  min-height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: The code you have here works.

Comment: take an important to min height

Comment: yes i tried that as well but no luck

Comment: @hussain Please define your issue more clearly. Bootstrap defines a `min-height` for `.navbar` which you have overridden. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If I paste this code into a Fiddle with just the basic Bootstrap files, it reduces the min-height to 15px. The code you have here doesn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I updated my question thats all i have in my code for navbar.

Comment: @BSMP I posted the code in fiddle but nothing happened. Should I add anything to it? Yea just tested it again, Its not working

Comment: @hussain not to be rude but is that a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Right now everyone is pluging in Bootstrap's CSS file in a JSFiddle, CodePen or Stack Snippet and not seeing an issue. **Please demonstrate the problem and clarify, clarify, clarity.**

Comment: Thats all i have in my code i am not sure what else i can add, I wish i can create fiddle or something but not authorize on these sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite the Bootstrap CSS.
In your HTML file put the Bootstrap link first then put your link to your css file after. Then you can go about editing the navbar class you want.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="location/filename.css">
```

Comment: thats how it is in my index.html

Comment: instead of editing the navbar.container-panel, try to edit just the navbar

Comment: @BigMonkey89WithaLeg overriding `.navbar` or using the OP's selector `.navbar.container-panel` will have the same affect if the OP's styles are included after the Bootstrap styles. The only difference is the OP's selector has a higher specificity than just `.navbar`.

Comment: well! i need to have a helper class other wise it will apply to all navbar in application.

Comment: @hussain you can do the _"helper"_ class as you have done or you can move the helper class up to a parent/ancestor element and use it to scope each menu with, i.e. `.primary-navbar .navbar` → `<div class="primary-navbar tab-content"><nav class="navbar"></nav></div>`. The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to create a bunch of different helper classes.

Comment: Thanks i got it working your suggestion definitely helped!